# Setting up virtual host with MAMP not working correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mamp, virtualhost

I am trying to create a virtual host using the instructions in this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoCDWyKoBFY

I am able to set it up, but when I type in the url I have set up as my virtual host (example: thissite.dev), it doesn't lead to the same page as I have set up for my public folder (which I set up as the path).  It leads to a page that says "It works!".  I never set up a view that says this...I am not sure why it is not leading to the public folder.  Also, going to any subview does not work.  For example, going to thissite.dev/artists does not work (this works fine using localhost:8888).  It will read with the error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /artists was not found on this server.
```

Not sure why it isn't working.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MAMP or MAMP PRO?

If you are using MAMP PRO then you don't need to add your hosts file or httpd-vhosts file..

In MAMP Pro, you will see a tab called ‘Hosts’. Click this tab & do the following:

1. Click the + to add a new host
2. Give the new host a ‘Server Name’ - in this example, let’s just call it:
   local.your-site-name.dev (the same as we did in the httpd-vhosts.conf file)
3. Browse to the document root and select the correct folder